# Does Deadpool age?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool

When Wade gets his healing abilities and becomes Deadpool, he's cured of his cancer. His ability to regenerate his body works super fast and basically makes him 'immortal' so I was wondering does he age as well or is the growing old process just slowed down and would be become 'old' at the age of, let's say 5000?

So in the movie, he wants to be with Vanessa but if he doesn't age Vanessa would just grow old while Deadpool stays young?
Could his aging process be compared to Wolverines or is it better/worse?

Comment: Deadpool is not cured of his cancer. When he gets his healing factor, so does his cancer, becoming super cancer. His healing factor fights it at an accelerated rate, but neither wins. Hence his face. And anti-telepathic brain. And insanity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the X-Force "Messiah War" story arc (specifically X-Force/Cable: Messiah War #1, May '09.) Deadpool appears 1000 years in the future, still alive. Although we never see what he looks like underneath his mask, he doesn't appear to have aged.

[image: Image from X-Force/Cable: Messiah War #1, May '09.]

..although this is specifically the comic and not the movie.

Comment: Good enough for me :-)
I suppose it will be the same in the movies.

Comment: That image is from X-Force/Cable: Messiah War #1, May '09, not Cable #13. Mine are from cable 13, notice the complete style change.

Comment: Oh silly me I copied the wrong volume number off my list. Yep, can't deny yours is a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 4):

### Background Information:

In the mainstream comics, Messiah War Part 2 (Cable #13), we see the 800 year old and 1000 year old Deadpool. His typical super-cancer face and skin. Since he doesn't have the typical old man hair or wrinkly skin clues that we expect from someone having aged, all we have is his statement that ***"I'm not healing like I used to."*** We also know that Wolverine ages slowly due to his mutant healing factor, and since Deadpool has a copied version of that, we know that Deadpool must age.

800 Year old:
[image]

1000 Year old:
[image]

He doesn't look any different 200 years later. His eyes are redder, but that's likely just a X-Force related stylistic choice. Wolverine here has time-jumped, while Deadpool took the long way round.

### In regards to the movie:

Wade is no longer just given a copy of Wolverine's mutant healing ability. Instead, he is forced to develop his own. The depicted scenes in Deadpool and X-Men show that Wade and Logan have similar healing times for minor wounds. Wade is shown to take days to regrow his hand, which is taken from his first ongoing comic series, where his healing factor is significantly reduced to the modern levels. The constant comparisons to Wolverine would seem to indicate that the production intends for Wolverine and Deadpool to have similar levels of healing as they would in the comics. We have seen that Wolverine has only aged a bit since his colonial era date of birth ("He could be older than you, Professor" line in X1). Ergo Deadpool will likely age at the same rate. **But we have yet to have a full answer** in Movie canon.

Answer (score 0):

Deadpool will most likely age at a slower rate but his healing factor isn't really that much better than Wolverine's. Deadpool's heling factor isn't even the reason  that he can't die. Wolverine can always instantly heal. Deadpool can heal normal wounds in a matter of seconds like Wolverine, but being dismembered takes time as seen in the movies and a lot in comics. In the comics, you barely see him heal, rather you see another seen where he appears to have already healed later on. Deadpool's interaction  with Death made Thanos give Deadpool eternal life. (Sad for Death since he can't see her unless he dies) Deadpool can't heal close to as well as Wolverine in a certain amount of time. Deadpool does prove to be able to continue being active (like a zombie) while being  injured and dismembered. He also seems to still feel pain. As for the main question, Deadpool will most likely age at a much slower rate than Vanessa (Doubt we would notice though because of his deformed face).